# weird behavior with jquery

Tags: jquery, templates, underscore.js

I've removed previous question because I found the problem is in jQuery itself.

Imagine this code :

```
var el = $('<ul><li/></ul><a id="clickMe">click me!</a><p>').find('#clickMe');
```

Why the clickMe isn't found ?

Comment: you could use event delegation, but your problem is much simpler, just move the `.append` call to before `var clickMeEl = ...`

Comment: thanks, but it didn't worked for me. I've completely re-asked my question. please look at it if you can help me further.

Comment: yeah, this way it would not find the element because it's not appended to the DOM :)

Comment: @gustavohenke no need to append element to the DOM for using transversal methods on object

Comment: Ah, right, I knew that. I've read his code wrong, that's why the comment...

Comment: @gustavohenke lol, I just saw OP edited question, nothing to do with his previous question, quite confusing IMO

Comment: forget this, it's getting too chatty. Upvoted you btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.find()` looks for descendants, use in your case `filter()` instead:

```
var el = $('<ul><li/></ul><a id="clickMe">click me!</a><p>').filter('#clickMe');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qmrpm/)

NOTe: in your html string, you are not closing `<p>` tag.

Comment: thanks, looks like I've to read jquery documentation more carefully next time.